# Hide Content via JS Calls

Tags: javascript, iframe-resizer

I have a page that is not on the same domain and I want to be able to hide the header and footer when it is loaded in another specific site.

Can this be done using iframe-resizer?  I have used it before and it works great but never tried cross communication and think that I will hit a security issue.

I was hoping that I could call postMessage to a JS function on the child page to hide the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yep I think that using postMessage would work, although you might get a bit of a flash, as it wouldn't be sent until the iFrame had loaded.

You could also look at usings something like `if (window.location !== top.location) {...}`.